# Remove Bottom Space From UITextView

Tags: iphone, uitextview

UITextView adds a little extra space to the bottom of the text. This isn't an extra line of text, but space that effects scrolling.

Is there any way to remove this space? I have attempted to use contentInset, contentOffset and contentSize but they all seem to have no effect.

Comment: Did you try negative content inset values?

Comment: Yes. Doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a very good solution at http://www.hanspinckaers.com/multi-line-uitextview-similar-to-sms.